# How to get nil object when there is no record for a specific value in where clause in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, where-clause

Currently, i am fetching the user records by using phone number field in Where query in rails like below.

```
users = User.where(phone: ["123421341234", "123423144", "123423144","444633333",,,,,,,,,,,,])
```

i have the user records, for the first three mobile numbers. But for the 4'th mobile number(444633333), there is no user record in the table, so for this user i want to get the "nil" object.(if user exists then the user object should be returned)

How can i change the above query. the resultant array should contain the objects in the sequence(in the search array sequence)

Comment: you can try something like this `[137,145,200].map { |id| User.find_by(phone: id) }`. Because `where` will neglect the `record not found exception`

Comment: But the queries are increasing. in single query i want to fetch all the records. my data base contains crores of users.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this without making so many queries to the DB is to load all users by the phone_number you already have first then map your phone_numbers to the users found

```rb
phones_numbers = [7799569, 7818111, 7820442, 78343033, 78347700, 7836863, 7837873, 7837898, 7838025, 7838442]
users = User.where(phone_number: phones_numbers)

users = phones_numbers.map { |number| users.find_by(phones_number: number) }
```

the users loaded will be cached in the memory so even if there are queries they run time will be insignificant

you can also use `#detect` if you wanna do this on ruby/rails level

```rb
#same stuff as above

users = phones_numbers.map { |number| users.detect { |user| user.phones_number == number } }
```